# Meteor App & iOS Status Bar

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, statusbar

I have a Meteor app on iOS and I have trouble specifying the behavior of the Status bar. Currently, the top of the app and the iOS status bar merge, and I'd like them not to:

[image: Merging :(]

I've tried :

```
App.setPreference('StatusBarOverlaysWebView', 'false');
```

in my settings.json file to no avail. The built config.xml file shows :

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Cordova StatusBar plugin for Meteor](https://github.com/Differential/meteor-mobile-cookbook/blob/master/iOS/Status%20Bar.md).

When you install the plugin just add the following code:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
   if(Meteor.isCordova){
       StatusBar.hide();
   }
});
```